# SQL Join with 2 columns when one of them is NULL/Blank

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have 2 tables like this: 
[image]

I want to join both #tmp1 & #tmp2 for Columns : Col2 & Col3 . But if the value of either of these columns is blank or Null, I want to ignore that column and just look at one. 
So for example here, when I join where Col2 is ABC, I should get both DEF & Blank for Col3.

I hope I'm making some sense here. Apologize if it's not clear enough.

Comment: Not sure I'm following. Can you share the result you're expecting for this sample data set please?

Comment: @Mureinik: Ok, So when I join #tmp1 & #tmp2 for Col2 & Col3, I want:

`'Test1','ABC','DEF'
'Test1','ABC',''
'Test2',AAA','BBB'
'Test2','CCC','BBB'`

Comment: What is the condition for joining the tables. Is it a cross join?

Comment: @navigator: I'm not sure on that either... Any join that works I guess.

Comment: Why would it return a record matching `ccc`?  That doesn't `join` on any of the fields...

Comment: @sgeddes: It matches the col3 for the value: BBB in both the tables.

Comment: Do you expect 4 results to come back with 3 columns or 2 results to come back with 6 columns?  4 results would require some sort of `union` with additional logic.  The later would require a `join`.

Comment: @sgeddes: 4 Results with 3 columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `union` for this checking if at least 1 of the 2 columns is the same using `exists`:

```
select col1, col2, col3
from tmp1 t1
where exists (select 1
              from tmp2 t2
              where t1.col2 = t2.col2 or t1.col3 = t2.col3)
union 
select col1, col2, col3
from tmp2 t2
where exists (select 1
              from tmp1 t1
              where t1.col2 = t2.col2 or t1.col3 = t2.col3)
```

- [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8e6c2/1)

---

Results:

```
|  col1 | col2 | col3 |
|-------|------|------|
| test1 |  abc |  def |
| test2 |  aaa |  bbb |
| test1 |  abc |      |
| test2 |  ccc |  bbb |
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell from your example what columns you want to join but to solve the "null" problem you do it like this

```
SELECT *
FROM T1
JOIN T2 ON COALESCE(T1.COL1,T2.COL1) = T2.COL1
         AND COALESCE(T1.COL2,T2.COL2) = T2.COL2
```

If T1.COL1 or T1.COL2 are null it will use the value of the table it is joining to.  This allows null to be a "wildcard".

or if T2 is the table with nulls

```
SELECT *
FROM T1
JOIN T2 ON T1.COL1 = COALESCE(T2.COL1,T1.COL1)
         AND T1.COL2 = COALESCE(T2.COL2,T1.COL2)
```